# PyQt + QtWebkit behind a proxy

Tags: python, ssl, https, pyqt, qtwebkit

I'm writing a PyQt (Python bindings for the all-powerful Qt library) application and a small part of my application needs a web browser (hint, OAuth). So I started using QtWebkit, which is fantastic by the way. The only hitch is I would like to allow users behind a proxy to use my application.

I have read about the QNetworkProxy class in the QtNetwork package and figure it should do the trick. The only problem is when I create and apply the proxy, it works just fine over HTTP, but when I pass it a HTTPS (SSL) URL, it gives me the following errors:

```
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv3_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_error_string
```

Note: when I run...

```
QtNetwork.QSslSocket.supportsSsl()
```

.. it returns false. So that's proof of my problem.

Here's my main code (it's right before my creationg of my QApplication):

```
proxy = QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy()
proxy.setType(QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.Socks5Proxy)
proxy.setHostName('localhost');
proxy.setPort(1337)
QtNetwork.QNetworkProxy.setApplicationProxy(proxy);
```

I got the code from [here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qnetworkproxy.html) but the example was written in C++, not Python so I'm not quite sure if I translated it properly. That could be the problem.

**EDIT:** I've tried it over a SOCKS5 and an HTTP proxy and they both throw the same error.

Comment: Do SSL connections without a proxy work?

Comment: I don't know, my current situation doesn't allow me to test that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was working on Windows XP (32-bit) with Python 2.6 and PyQt 4.7.4. The reason that...

```
QtNetwork.QSslSocket.supportsSsl()
```

was returning **false** was because I had not installed **OpenSSL binaries** to my system.

To solve the problem I went [here](http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) to download the binaries. Before they would properly install I had to also get the **Visual C++ 2008 Redistributables** install from Microsoft.

Everything is working great now!